# I have a problem in my Smart Contract in Withdraw Function

Tags: solidity, web3js, cpp-ethereum

```
   function withdraw () public OnlyOwner {
       for (uint i = 0 ; i<= funders.length ; i++) {
           address funder = funders[i];
           addresstoFund[funder] = 0 ;
       }

       funders = new address[](0); // Syntax for reseting the array 
       payable (msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);

   
   }
```

My error is this :

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted
{
"originalError": {
"code": 3,
"data": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032",
"message": "execution reverted"
}
}
```

Can somebody help me

Answer (score 2):

There is a small error in your `for` loop. You are trying to loop it from 0 till `funders.length`. But the loop should have been executed till `funders.length - 1` since the length of an array is 1 more than the index of the last element added to an array. Try it with this:

```
for (uint i = 0 ; i < funders.length ; i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

send and transfer functions has 2300 limit of gas. You might be passing that limit